# Do you need to explicity close a Java KeyStore input stream?

Tags: java, keystore, jks

When reading in a KeyStore using a FileInputStream as follows, does one need to explicitly close the input-steam to stop system resources being wasted ?

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("keystore.jks");
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(fin, password);

//  Is this line needed ??
fin.close();
```

Is this FileInputStream closed automatically by the load() method or is explicit manually intervention required?

Comment: If you create the stream, you are responsible for closing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this FileInputStream closed automatically by the load() method or is explicit manually intervention required?

yes it required to close to over come unnecessary leaks.

Checkout example given in java doc of `KeyStore`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try this test

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("keystore.jks") {
        public void close() throws java.io.IOException {
            System.out.println("close");
        }
    };
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keystore.load(fin, "changeit".toCharArray());
```

and you will see that close() is not called

Comment: Excellent example, unfortunately I can only pick one right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitly use [org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closequietly](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29) when dealing with streams and APIs you are not sure about